# Adding a fragment on top of another fragment and clear focus of bottom fragment

Tags: android

I have created one fragment from the activity. After that I have added another fragment top of the previous fragment. I have added `Android: clickable="true"` in my top fragment so that I can grab the click event. Everything is working fine. Now I am trying to implement the external Keyboard navigation and found that bottom fragment still grab the focus.

I have tried different ways to clear the focus of bottom fragment when I am in the top fragment. But could not find a solution.

Comment: I solved the issue. I just invisible the bottom fragment from the top using findFragmentBytag.

Comment: @Jahid please don't add code formatting over keywords that are not necessarily *factual code*. It makes it very difficult to read and it's actually [not very welcomed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755/213575)

Comment: @Braiam I get it now, sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue. I just invisible the bottom fragment from the top using findFragmentBytag to find the bottom fragment.

Example code segment:

```
Fragment bottom = ( Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(bottom.TAG); 
if (bottom.isVisible()) { 
    bottom.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: A sample code to do that invisibling would be better.

Comment: Invisible the bottom fragment from top fragment onResume and visible back from onDestroy. Example: Fragment bottom = ( Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(bottom.TAG);
        if (bottom.isVisible()) {
            bottom.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}

Comment: @Jahid Please accept the answer and give me a up vote. My reputation is not so good yet.